# Is a person from Charlotte, North Carolina called a Charlatan?

Tags: nouns

Is a person from Charlotte North Carolina called a Charlatan? Or is there some other term for a person from that place?

Comment: I'm sure it's done.

Comment: In jest, that is.

Comment: Made me laugh, but that alone doesn't make this a good question. Look up [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) and see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities) (in its 'List of adjectivals and demonyms for cities), is **Charlottean**.

The [Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlatan_(disambiguation)) for 'C/charlatan' does not license the use of this as a synonym, and neither do CED, M-W, Macmillan, RHK Webster's, Collins or AHD.

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia page, I wonder if city names are much more likely to start with the letter S (than any other letter).

Comment: That's not how I got to the Wikipedia article, and I wouldn't have thought it likely to produce a result. 'Demonym', however, was not a gimme from the question. I don't answer questions I think are LMGTFY, as I feel it harms the site's credibility.

Comment: This is totally a LYGTFY question though. It's a question of simple fact about a fairly well known city. If you Google, "what are people from charlotte called", the answer is in the first result...

Comment: And the pronunciation is shar-lot-**tay**-an, too, so the joke's a bit harder to make that it might seem.