# Phrase to indicate exception

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is there alternative word/phrase to replace commonly used "save for" / "except" to indicate an exception in a sentence.

for example, the following statement:
there was no evidence to associate the Company to the premises, save for the expired tenancy.

I am looking for alternative ways to replace "save for" and "except" which is suitable to the context of the sentence

Thank you

Comment: *There's nothing **bar** this exception*. But you could just switch to *There's **only** this exception.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use '**but**'. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/but) has

> **but**
> <sub>PREPOSITION</sub>
>
> **1** Except; apart from; other than.
> *we were never anything but poor*

So the sentence could be

> There was no evidence but the expired tenancy to associate the company to the premises.

Or, as there *was* evidence, rephrase as

> The *only* evidence to associate the company *with* the premises was the expired tenancy [agreement].

Comment: I appreciate your help thank you very much

Comment: .......... LMGTFY / ELL

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it came from my head, not from google.

Comment: I was speaking about the question. Lacking easily available research, and rewrites ELL level. Answering encourages further inappropriate / inappropriately presented questions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth do you mean like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525407/is-a-person-from-charlotte-north-carolina-called-a-charlatan)

Comment: No. Looking up synonyms of a non-proper word actually mentioned by OP in any thesaurus will give instant results. Looking up 'C/charlatan' in a single reference (say a dictionary) may and probably will not give a decisive answer. Even OED states that non-inclusion is not proof that a candidate is not a word.